# Pandas list comprehension in a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I would like to pull out the price at the next day's open currently stored in (row + 1) and store it in a new column, if some condition is met.

```
df['b']=''

df['shift']=''

df['shift']=df['open'].shift(-1)

df['b']=df[x for x in df['shift'] if df["MA10"]>df["MA100"]]
```

Comment: If you want to use the result of list comprehension as an index, you should use: `df[[x for x in df['shift'] if df["MA10"]>df["MA100"]]]`, but I think this will raise some exception. Please post your sample data and desired result.

Comment: @HYRY Thanks for your comment. I posted a link to my sample data. I used your suggestion before posting and got the error "invalid syntax" as I mentioned.

Comment: @user1374969: count the number of brackets in HYRY's suggestion, and then count the number in yours.

Comment: @DSM Thanks. If I go with HYRY's I receive the ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() python doesnt know whether this is bitwise or the entire column comparison.

Comment: That's what HYRY meant by "raise some exception".  Your attempts had both syntax problems and interface problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few approaches.  Using `apply`:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("bondstack.csv")
>>> df["shift"] = df["open"].shift(-1)
>>> df["b"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["shift"] if row["MA10"] > row["MA100"] else np.nan, axis=1)
```

which produces

```
>>> df[["MA10", "MA100", "shift", "b"]][:10]
        MA10      MA100      shift          b
0  16.915625  17.405625  16.734375        NaN
1  16.871875  17.358750  17.171875        NaN
2  16.893750  17.317187  17.359375        NaN
3  16.950000  17.279062  17.359375        NaN
4  17.137500  17.254062  18.640625        NaN
5  17.365625  17.229063  18.921875  18.921875
6  17.550000  17.200312  18.296875  18.296875
7  17.681250  17.177500  18.640625  18.640625
8  17.812500  17.159375  18.609375  18.609375
9  17.943750  17.142813  18.234375  18.234375
```

For a more vectorized approach, you could use

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("bondstack.csv")
>>> df["b"] = np.nan
>>> df["b"][df["MA10"] > df["MA100"]] = df["open"].shift(-1)
```

or my preferred approach:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("bondstack.csv")
>>> df["b"] = df["open"].shift(-1).where(df["MA10"] > df["MA100"])
```

Comment: can't tell you how much I have appreciated (on this site) your thoughtful suggestions and multiple ways of viewing the same question. Thank you.

Comment: For approach #3 I get time series object has no attribute 'where' given where is a numpy attribute I used the np.where() with the same error. Do you have an idea of what is happening?

Comment: Which version of `pandas` are you using?  I'm using 0.10.1, and the above code works just fine on your data.

Comment: Ok, yes, think it's running version '0.9.1'. With df['open'].shift(-1),  I was trying to pull the **next** row's value (i+1) from where the condition in 'where' is met. I.E., at the row where we satisfy the condition defined in 'where', call it i ,  df["b"] should store the value in df['open'] on the **next** i+1 **after that condition is observed**. (Right now, it appears to store the df['open'] value starting at-- 1 shifted from the very---beginning--- of the file). Seems that simply df["open"][i+1] will not do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Call the condition M.  If you had [Monday open=1, M=True; Tuesday open=2, M=False; Wednesday open=3, M=True], do you want Monday's b value to be 2 or 3?  What b value should Tuesday have?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. If you have time, I edited my original comment in the section above, in an attempt to clarify what I mean to do with df['open'].shift(-1)    the .csv file was changed too.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying DSM's approach 3, stating True/False values in `np.where` explicitly:

```
#numpy.where(condition, x, y)
df["b"] = np.where(df["MA10"] > df["MA100"], df["open"].shift(-1), np.nan)
```

Using list comprehension explicitly:

```
#[xv if c else yv for (c,xv,yv) in zip(condition,x,y)]      #np.where documentation
df['b'] = [ xv if c else np.nan for (c,xv) in zip(df["MA10"]> df["MA100"], df["open"].shift(-1))]
```